# Need clarification for using linq in asp.net mvc apps

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities, model-binding

I have method to retrieve data from DAL as follows:

```
public List<Comment> GetAllComment(int _UserID)
    {
        using (var context = new TourBlogEntities1())
        {
            var AllComment = from s in context.Comments
                             where s.UserID == _UserID
                             select s;

            return AllComment.ToList<Comment>();
        }
    }
```

Now I'm trying to call this method from my controller as follwos:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewComment(PostComment model)
    {
        var business = new Business();

        var entity = new Comment();
        entity.Comments = model.Comments.Comments;
        //entity.PostID = model.Posts.PostID; HOW TO PASS POSTID???
        entity.UserID = business.GetUserID(User.Identity.Name);

        business.PostComment(entity);

        var CommentsListFromEntity = business.GetAllComment(business.GetUserID(User.Identity.Name));

        var viewmodel = new PostComment();
        viewmodel.CommentsListFromModel = CommentsListFromEntity.ToList<CommentInfo>(); // Error is showing here  

        return View("ViewPost", viewmodel);
    }
```

I bind my view with the model, but could not use the list, Even if I try to pass the list itself to view, still I can't use that list in view!

My model class is as follows:

```
public class PostComment
{
    public PostComment()
    {
        Posts = new NewPost();
        Comments = new CommentInfo();
        User = new UserInfoModel();
    }

    public NewPost Posts { get; set; }
    public CommentInfo Comments { get; set; }
    public UserInfoModel User { get; set; }
    public List<CommentInfo> CommentsListFromModel { get; set; }

}
```

So how to use the list in view? I need the help badly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return an ActionResult from controller actions:

```
public ActionResult GetAllComment(int _UserID)
{
    using (var context = new TourBlogEntities1())
    {
        var AllComment = from s in context.Comments
                         where s.UserID == _UserID
                         select s;

        return View(AllComment.ToList());
    }
}
```

Now the corresponding view could be strongly typed to `List<Comment>`:

```
@model List<Comment
```

and then you could loop through the model and display it:

```
@foreach (var comment in Model) 
{
    <div><@comment.Text</div>
}
```

---

UPDATE:

If this method is in your BLL you could invoke it in your controller action and pass the result to the view:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int userID)
{
    List<Comment> comments = bll.GetAllComment(userID);
    return View(comments);
}
```

---

UPDATE 2:

If you need to pass other properties to the view in addition to this list then you define a view model containing all the necessary information:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and then have your controller action pass this view model to the view:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int userID)
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Comments = bll.GetAllComment(userID);
    model.Foo = "that's the foo";
    model.Bar = "that's the bar";
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally your view is strongly typed to the new view model:

```
@model MyViewModel

<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Foo)</h2>

@foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
{
    <div>@comment.Text</div>
}

<span>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Bar)</span>
```

Comment: But I'm not writing the method in controller, this is in BLL, now I need to call the method from Action method & then pass the list to view. In that case what should be the return type in BLL mehtod?

Comment: In this case you would keep the method signature as you have it currently and then invoke it in your controller action. I've updated my answer to shown an example.

Comment: Darin, I was mistakenly tagged my post as mvc 2, but I'm using mvc 3, so could you please show me a way to bind the list to view using razor syntax? Another thing, I know its not possible to bind more than one model to the same view, is it possible to bind the model & list together? Thnaks.

Comment: I have edited my question, it might give you some more information.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the Razor syntax. If you want to pass a List and some other model to the view then you define a new class containing 2 properties: the list and the other model and then have your controller action pass this new class to the view. The view will then become strongly typed to this new class: `@model MyViewModel`. And then you could access its properties. For example `@foreach (var comment in Model.Comments) { ... }`.

Comment: I did exactly the same in my model class & controller, but getting a run time error in view while using the for loop, its saying object reference not set to an instance of object!May be I'm getting closer!

Comment: Make sure you have passed the model to the view: `return View(model);` and that the `Comments` property of this model is not null.

Comment: Thanks for all your great help & greater patience, Now its working fine.

Comment: Darin, Can you please give me  a suggestion over the following situation: I have a list of post to show on viewpost page, I can pass the list to the view now, but I want to show one at a time with two button as next & previous to navigate through the post. How can/should I implement this? Should I pick the button event by using jquery? What would be the best practice?

Comment: You should not be passing a list of posts to the view in this case. You would pass a single post. Then you would have 2 actionlinks which would be pointing to a controller action and passing the page number and you should perform the pagination on the server.